# How do i add image picker on Android App?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, gradle, imagepicker

im triying to use an image picker so I can open the gallery and choose a pic for the user profile.
Apparently the [built-in image picker](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/13/features/photopicker) works only on Android 13 (API 33) so in order to add this feature i have to add [this library](https://github.com/Dhaval2404/ImagePicker).

The first step is not clear to me:

*Gradle dependency:*

```
allprojects {
   repositories {
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
   }
}
```

```
implementation 'com.github.dhaval2404:imagepicker:2.1'
```

*If you are yet to Migrate on AndroidX, Use support build artifact:*

```
implementation 'com.github.dhaval2404:imagepicker-support:1.7.1'
```

I added the second section code in build.gradle (App level) in order to make it work but when i try to implement it in my code [I get this message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQG9V.png)

Adding the dependency suggested by Android Studio does not solve the problem, 99% I'm missing something.

Comment: Your android is androidX. So use the above dependency: `implementation 'com.github.dhaval2404:imagepicker:2.1'` and make sure that your internet is enabled.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you didn't know, you can already open a file picker that only displays photos - the Photo Picker thing is a new feature in Android 13 (which isn't even released yet), so [this is still the standard way to do it](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common#Storage)!

```
const val REQUEST_IMAGE_OPEN = 1

fun selectImage() {
    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT).apply {
        type = "image/*"
        addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
    }
    // opens the standard document browser, filtered to images
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_IMAGE_OPEN)
}

override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_OPEN && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        val fullPhotoUri: Uri = data.data
        // Do work with full size photo saved at fullPhotoUri
    }
}
```

There's actually two versions at the link - one uses `GET_CONTENT` which *copies* the image, the other uses `OPEN_DOCUMENT` which gives you a *URI* pointing to the existing file on disk. Read the descriptions to see which works best for whatever you're doing.

So yeah, if you want something that looks like a plain photo gallery, you'll either need the new picker or a library that does similar. If you just want to let the user load an image though, the standard document browser should be familiar

Answer (score 0):

When you add a new library reference in your app/bundle.gradle file:

```
dependencies {
 implementation 'com.github.dhaval2404:imagepicker-support:1.7.1'
// ..
}
```

be sure to run Gradle sync:

[image: Gradle sync button]

Then to need to add `import` in the java/kotlin source code:

```kotlin
import com.github.dhaval2404.imagepicker.ImagePicker
```

just like in the [sample of that library](https://github.com/Dhaval2404/ImagePicker/blob/master/sample/src/main/kotlin/com.github.dhaval2404.imagepicker/sample/MainActivity.kt)